# String compression implementation in C

Tags: algorithm, c, strings, compression

I implemented basic string compression algorithm that uses the counts of repeated characters. For example: the string aabcccccaaa would become a2b1c5a3. What do you think about this, is there a better way to do this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* compressString(char* arr, int size);

int main() {

  char arr[] = "aabcccccaa";
  char *str;
  printf("Before compression: %s\n", arr);
  str = compressString(arr, strlen(arr));
  printf("After compression: %s\n", str);
  // free allocated memory
  free(str);
  return 0;
}

char* compressString(char* str, int len) {
  char last = str[0];
  char *buf = (char *)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
  int count = 1;
  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    if (last == str[i]) {
      count++;
    } else {
      buf[j++] = last;
      buf[j++] += count + '0';
      last = str[i];
      count = 1;
    }
  }
  buf[j++] = last;
  buf[j] += count + '0';
  buf[j] = '\0';
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: Thoughts: _const correctness_, comment on encoding of `count` (_why_ single character/digit?), look into [PackBits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackBits) to see how to avoid encoding a length "for every source character change".

Comment: Please don't update your code with changes after you've received answers, see [What to do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: Seeing your edit to revision 5: it is detrimental to have _encode run_ in more than one place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### A couple problems

- You don't allocate enough space for the return buffer.  You need to allocate `2*len + 1` bytes to handle the worst cast scenario.  The `+1` is for the null terminating byte.
- If the count goes above 9, you will output a non-digit character instead of a digit.  If the count goes above 256, the digit will wrap around back to `'1'` and your compression will have failed to encode the original string.

Comment: @CodeCrack: perhaps you should get a rough overview of **existing** compression algorithms before reinventing the wheel  in a particularly non-circular shape. For one thing this would show you all the ways that have been invented for storing counts efficiently (variable-length encodings based on bytes, nibbles or bits, Huffman-encoding of counts, arithmetic coding of counts, and so on). Run-length encodings like yours are often found in bitmaps (unsurprisingly called RLE bitmaps); looking at those might give you interesting ideas. Most of your questions have already been answered ages ago...

Comment: I don't know what will be put in `buf` following a character from the input - `buf[j++] += count + '0';` will add to whatever has been there before. I do have an inkling the last count will be overwritten, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Failing to document *a non-`NULL` return value will need to be `free()`d* is an even bigger foul than not checking the value from `malloc()` - actually freeing in spite of an immediately following return from `main()` is proper.
The string literal in main differs from your example.
The code presented does not work as specified: the string returned lacks the last count.
The handling of `len` 0 is insufficient.
As you are aware, "adding the digit to `buf[j]`" is wrong.