# RLE-like string compression in clojure

Tags: beginner, clojure, compression

There have been already many similar questions to this one (e.g. [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115538/algorithm-for-simple-string-compression) and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116194/string-compression-implementation-in-c), just to point two), but I did not find any for clojure.

The goal is to compress a string in a RLE-like way: i.e. each character "run" is replaced by the character and the count of the run. Some examples:

```
aaaabbccc       -->      a4b2c3
b               -->      b1
aaaaaaaaaaaa    -->      a9a3
```

Some remarks:

- For now, I do not care about the possible optimisation that runs with the length of 1 can omit the count. (E.g. the output could be `b` instead of `b1`.)
- If there are more than `n > 9` characters in a run, then it is split up into two or more runs, like `9 + 9 + 9 + ... + k = n`, where `k <= 9`.
- For now, I do not care if the "compressed" string will be longer than the original one (this is the case e.g. for an input containing only single characters, like: `abcde --> a1b1c1d1e1`).

That said, please see my implementation below:

### Source

```
(defn countrepetitions [s]
      (if (empty? s) 0
          (loop [acts (vec s) ch (first acts) cnt 1]
                (if (= ch (first(rest acts)))
                   (recur (rest acts) ch (inc cnt))
                    cnt))))

(defn mycompress [s]
      (loop [acts s encoded "" cnt1 (countrepetitions acts)]
            (if (= 0 cnt1)
                encoded
                (let [cnt2 (if (< cnt1 10) cnt1 9)]
                     (recur (subs acts cnt2) (str encoded (first acts) cnt2) (countrepetitions (subs acts cnt2)))))))
```

### Tests

```
(deftest a-test
  (testing "compressor"
    (is (= "" (mycompress "")))
    (is (= "a2" (mycompress "aa")))
    (is (= "a1b8a1c7a3" (mycompress "abbbbbbbbacccccccaaa")))
    (is (= "b9b3" (mycompress "bbbbbbbbbbbb")))))
```

### Questions

In particular, I would be interested in the following, but any other remark/suggestion is also welcome:

- Is there a more efficient way (either in terms of readability or speed) to implement `countrepetitions`, or maybe leave it out completely?
- Are there any other tests worth adding? Or can you find a "counter-example" (i.e. a test case, for which the implementation does not work correctly)?

Comment: You could use [partition-by](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-by) to count consecutive occurrences, instead of the implicit recursion, for example: `(map (juxt first count) (partition-by identity "abbbbbbbbacccccccaaa"))`

Comment: @Shlomi thank you, after some experimentation I came up with the following based on your suggestion: `(apply str (flatten (map (juxt first count) (apply concat (map #(partition-all 9 %)  (partition-by identity s)))))))`. Definitely shorter then my original attempt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're splitting a list up into a number of chunks, it's worth looking into the `partition` function (and related functions).

A string is just a list of characters, and you just want to split it when the character changes, so `(partition-by identity characters)` should be much simpler than what you have above.  You can pair that with another partition to make sure you have no chunks of > 9 characters:

```clj
(defn rle-chunks [string]
  (->> string
       (partition-by identity)
       (mapcat #(partition-all 9 %))))
```

Actually performing the compression is then just a case of calling `first` & `count` on each of these chunks, then converting back to a string:

```clj
(defn rle [input]
  (->> input
       rle-chunks
       (map (juxt first count))
       (apply concat)
       (apply str)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this much more readable than the solution I came up with based on the suggestion of @Shlomi: it is definitely more readable. Also, I was not aware of `mapcat` and did not remember the threading macro `->>`. Just one question: I think `(apply concat)` can be replaced with `(flatten)` in this case, to make it even shorter. What do you think?

Comment: @Attilio yeah, you're probably right.